# Uncapitalized automatic comment for close-as-duplicate vote

Tags: feature-request, bug

Anyone else noticed the not capitalized automatic comment when voting a question to be closed as duplicate?

> possible duplicate of *Title of the Original Question Here*.

Would it be too much to ask to spend the comment a capital P?
And how about a full stop at the end as well?

Comment: capital_P_dangit

Comment: I will try to find out where those comments are and whether mods can edit them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is … intentional:

[Capitalize "possible" in the automatically inserted comments when you vote to close as a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-cl)

I agree, it should be a complete sentence, but there is nothing we can do about it.

Comment: That `wontfix` "reason" might be one of the most absurd things I've ever read. It basically boils down to *the SABDFL likes it the way it is*. I don't like that attitude with `capital_P_dangit()` in WP core, and I equally dislike it with `lowercase_P_dangit()` in SE.